# ValueError: Location should be a string when using Geocoder in Python

Tags: python

Im trying to find city name with `geocoder` lib. I have float coordinates (lat and lng), I thing I did everything good (I have looked into their documentations) but I always get an error:

`ValueError: Location should be a string`

Error is in this line:

```
city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], mothod = 'reverse')
```

This is the code:

```
import geocoder

lat = 44.0207472303
lng = 20.9033038427
print(lat, lng)

city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], mothod = 'reverse')
city_name = str(city_name.city)

print(city_name)
```

Comment: It is `method='reverse'` not `mothod` in line `city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], mothod = 'reverse')`

Comment: Thanks, that was stupid from me, but I always get `None` as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [CodeIt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3091398/codeit)  mentioned, you should change this line

```
geocoder.google([lat, lng], mothod = 'reverse')
```

to this:

```
geocoder.google([lat, lng], method = 'reverse')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was stupid from me, but I always get `None` as result

Answer (score 1):

It is `method='reverse'` *not* `mothod` in this *line*

```
city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], mothod = 'reverse')
```

*Correct it to*:

```
city_name = geocoder.google([lat, lng], method = 'reverse')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was stupid from me, but I always get `None` as result

Comment: @taga That is a different question.

Comment: Please check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216439/always-getting-none-values-when-using-python-geocoder